# Accessing elements in submatrix in big matrix matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a big matrix divided into sub-matrices.

```
clear all
clc

X  = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
B1 = zeros(3,9);
B2 = zeros(3,3);
m1 = diag([11 12 13]);
m2 = diag([14 15 16]);
m3 = diag([17 18 19]);
G = [ X B1; B2 m1 m2 m3];
```

The result is

```
G =

     1     2     3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     4     5     6     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     7     8     9     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0    11     0     0    14     0     0    17     0     0
     0     0     0     0    12     0     0    15     0     0    18     0
     0     0     0     0     0    13     0     0    16     0     0    19
```

Now my question  is how to access to the diagonal elements of the sub-matrices (m1, m2, m3) whether starting from index i = 1 to i = 3, Or accessing to specific m, for example i = 2 for m2? Another question is Is it possible to access to sub-matrices by their names as an index into the big matrix? For example, `G(m1(1,1))`? I now this doesn't work but I wanna illustrate my point.

Answer (score 3):

**Accessing diagonals of submatrices**

To get the diagonal of a submatrix, you have to select the submatrix, then use the diag function:

```
diag(G(1:3,1:3))
```

**Labeling of submatrices**

You could define a label like this:

```
m1_s={[4:6],[4:6]}
```

which means row 4 to 6, column 4 to 6. To get the submatrix using `G(m1_s{:})`.

Obviously you can combine both techniques. For example get the diagonal of the submatrix m1:

```
diag(G(m1_s{:}))
```

The `{:}` is explained [here](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html), it converts the cell array `m1_s` to a comma seperated list. Writing `G(m1_s{:})` is the same as `G(m1_s{1},m1_s{2})`

/update:

A more dynamic way of labeling could be implemented using a function handle:

```
m_s=@(c)({[4:6],[1:3]+c*3})
```

Now you can use

```
m1_s=m_s(1)
G(m1_s)
```

Comment: but your approach will be difficult if I increase m. What I did simple. I did create a function `function index = m_index(i)

for a = 1:i
    j = 4;
    k = 1;
    while (k < a)
        j = j + 3;
        k = k + 1;
    end
end
index = j;
end` Now I am controlling the ms based on i indices. In the main(), `G(4, m_index(i)  )
    G(5, m_index(i)+1)
    G(6, m_index(i)+2)`

Comment: @CroCo: You are right, there are many ways to define it in a more dynamic way, but your function seems a bit overcomplicated. Isn't the function always returning `(i+1)*3+1` ?

Comment: `(i+1)*3+1` yes but this doesn't handle the first case in which `i=1`. In this case, it should return `4` not `7`.

Comment: I have tracked the output and it turns out for `1 4; 2 7; 3 10; 4 13`. In this case, I'm able to access to certain m without going through a loop. The function takes care of this loop.